# How to reset SQL Server 2008 Column based on years

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a leave software, and my problem is that i need to reset the leave days to default number of days (30 day) after one year. would you pleas help me with that. 
ps: I'm using VB.NET AND SQL SERVER.

```
create table Addemployees
( 
    Fname varchar (500), 
    Lname varchar (500), 
    ID int not null identity(1, 1) primary key, 
    CIN varchar (500), 
    fromD date, 
    toD date, 
    Email varchar(500), 
    phone varchar(500), 
    Leave_num int
)
```

This is the tablet that contains the column Leave_num that has the leave numbers inserted by the user

Comment: hi! what have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. but we will help you, if you have any problems in your code

Comment: Please, show table structure, sample data, expected outputs.

Comment: i really dont know how to do it, so i have tried difrent things but non of them woks;

Comment: UPDATE yourtable SET yourcolumn = 30 WHERE yourdate < DateAdd(yy, -1, GetDate()) -- this SQL will just update the column if yourdate is smaller than the current date minus one year

Comment: @Sami create table Addemployees(
Fname varchar (500),
Lname varchar (500),
ID   int not null identity(1, 1) primary key, 
CIN varchar (500),
fromD date,
toD  date,
Email varchar(500),
phone varchar(500),
Leave_num int,
) This is the tablet that contains the column Leave_num that has the leave numbers inserted by the user

Comment: please add your code to your question not in comments. Edit your question and put any additional code there, not here

Comment: So now we have a table with some information. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You might take a hard look at your datatypes at some point. They are crazy big. Names with 500 characters?  and phone numbers? I would also suggest you user better names thatn toD and fromD. Why not ToDate and FromDate. Hardly any more to type and massively clearer.

Comment: Before asking question, learn how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Eric thank you very much for your support that's really helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
update addemployees
set leave_num = 30
```

As for how you trigger this logic. There are many ways you could go about this. You'll need some sort of scheduler like an Agent job, or whatever else you have at your disposal to run this process on a recurring, scheduled, basis. The key thing is not to keep updating the `LeaveNum` if it's already been updated. You could maintain an extra column on each row indicating the last time they were reset. This is probably the simplest, but if it's truly an all-or-nothing type thing, and those dates will all be the same, that's sort of a waste of space.

You could then either create a separate table which just contains information  about when these once-a-year jobs run, or something like an [Extended Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql) (which is a little more involved to set up).

Whatever the solution you choose, Just save off the date (or even just the year), and then when your process runs, if the difference between the last update is greater than a year (or if the year of the last update is less than the current year) run your update, then update however you're storing that information; be it columns, a separate table, or an extended property.

Comment: That depends; what counts as "after a year"? January first? 365 days after the `fromD`? something else entirely? Is it the same for each person, or different?

Comment: And again, what is that logic?